# What is the Integration Toolkit use case? Can I use it to watch for Live Agent chat events like Chat End?

Tags: integration, liveagent

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/

I am confused about the usecase of this.

Can I use this on the page to invoke some functions on parent end to determine if, for example, the chat session has ended?

For example this method [(docs)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_onChatEnded.htm?search_text=onchatended):

`sforce.console.chat.onChatEnded(someFunction);`

Can the Integration Toolkit be used on side of our application and let invoke parent-side JS functions? Or it's use case is different?

The reason I am asking is because to use Integration Toolkit the domain where I use it has to be whitelisted in the settings, otherwise it's method are not available on the page and the error is thrown in the console:

`Service Cloud Toolkit API cannot be used with your browser.`

Thus, I can not test if the method works, and to add the domain to whitelist I need to get the information whether it's right to use the Toolkit in such a way.

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose of the "Integration Toolkit" is giving the ability to developers to interact with Service Console.

> The Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit provides you with
>   programmatic access to the Salesforce console so that you can extend
>   it to meet your business needs. With the Salesforce Console
>   Integration Toolkit, you can open and close tabs in the console to
>   streamline a business process.

Also this means you can use it only inside "Salesforce console". You can not use this toolkit to interact with Salesforce from external systems. I.e. you do not need to whitelist any additional domains. If you want to integrate with salesforce from external system you need to use some API (Rest/Soap/Bulk/etc.)